# Pythonic way of checking if all values in kwargs are the string "false"

Tags: python, python-3.4

Take `kwargs` i.e: `send_members`, `send_companies`, `send_reviewers`, each of which contains the string `'true'` or `'false'`.

If *all* the values in every `kwargs` are `'false'`, I want to display an error message e.g:

```
if (kwargs['send_members'] == 'false' and kwargs['send_companies'] == 'false' and
    kwargs['send_reviewers'] == 'false'):
        raise SomeError('at least one keyword needs to be true')
```

Is there a Pythonic way of checking if all the values in `kwargs` are the same, `'false'`? While the above example works, it gets very messy when I have 10 `kwargs`.

Comment: `if set(kwargs.values()) == {'false'}: ...`

Comment: This should work

    `if not [x for x in kwargs.values() if x != "false"]:`

Comment: @rtemperv Unfortunately, the values are strings, not instances of `bool`. (You could first map `bool` over `kwargs.values()`, though.)

Comment: re ``if not any(kwargs.values()):`` @rtemperv sorry it's a string true or false so that will not work as kwargs always contains values

Comment: My bad, updated answer

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary could you explain this a little more in an answer? Thank you.

Comment: A more important question might be, why in the world is your caller sending you *strings* when they should be sending in *bool*s?

Comment: @WayneWerner Good question I've changed this to a boolean now and used @gr1zzly be4r answer  by checking  ``== False``

Comment: I'll add a comment to grizz's question about a slight improvement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `all()`

```
if all(v == 'false' for v in kwargs.values()):
    print("All kwargs are false")
```

Comment: Based on the OPs changes (actually having the caller pass in `bool`s) then `any()` is a good choice: `if not any(kwargs.values()):`

Answer (score 0):

```
kwargs = {'send_members':'false', 'send_companies':'false', 'send_reviewers':'false'}

def v1 ():
    if set(kwargs.values()) == {'false'}:
    return 'all false!'

def v2 ():
    if not [x for x in kwargs.values() if x !='false']:
    return 'all false!'

def v3 ():
    if all(v == 'false' for v in kwargs.values()):
    return 'all false!'


In [10]: %timeit -n100 v1()
100 loops, best of 3: 1.05 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit -n100 v2()
100 loops, best of 3: 961 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit -n100 v3()
100 loops, best of 3: 10.3 µs per loop
```

Interestingly using all() seems about 10x slower.

Answer (score 0):

You could [also] use the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function which might be a little faster than `all()` because it will stop checking as soon as a failure is detected.

```
class SomeError(Exception): pass

testcases = [
    {'send_members': 'true', 'send_companies': 'false', 'send_reviewers': 'false'},
    {'send_members': 'false', 'send_companies': 'true', 'send_reviewers': 'false'},
    {'send_members': 'false', 'send_companies': 'false', 'send_reviewers': 'false'},
]

for kwargs in testcases:
    print(kwargs, end=' ')
    try:
        if any(value != 'false' for value in kwargs.values()):
            raise SomeError('at least one keyword needs to be true')
    except SomeError:
        print("At least one kwarg is not 'false'")
    else:
        print("OK, all kwargs are 'false'")
```